# Intent filter for SEND action in a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

I want users to be able to Share/Send to my app, but I don't want to start an activity (I just need to send some data on the network, and show a success message popup). I was imagining using a Broadcast Receiver for this, but the intent filter shown below, while it works when in a normal activity, doesn't work for a receiver (i.e. my app doesn't show in the list of things I can share to).

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Should I be using a receiver here, or is there some other way of catching a SEND intent without launching a full activity?

Answer (score 5):

> my app doesn't show in the list of things I can share to

Correct. That is because `ACTION_SEND` is used for activities. The ones who are initiating `ACTION_SEND` are calling `startActivity()`. You cannot respond to a `startActivity()` request with anything other than an `Activity`.

> is there some other way of catching a SEND intent without launching a full activity?

No. You are welcome to use `Theme.NoDisplay`, `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`, or something to have an activity with no UI, though. Just don't call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`, but instead do your work (e.g., kick off an `IntentService` to do your network I/O), and call `finish()`.